# How to verify if specific date is monday in php

Tags: php, jquery, date, datepicker

i have a script that generates week days with a next and preview. It workes perfect but i also added a callendar that is autosubmiting on change. the problem i have with it is that when i select a day and that day is monday is still goes me to last week. What i need is to verify if the selected day is monday and give $monday that date instead giving it the last week monday. Here is my script:

```
$date = strtotime(date($_GET['date']));
$monday = "";


if (isset($_GET['n_startdate'])) {
    $date = $_GET['n_startdate'];
    $lastweek = strtotime("next week", $date);
    $monday = strtotime("last Monday", $lastweek);
} else if ( isset($_GET['p_startdate'])) {
    $date = $_GET['p_startdate'];
    $lastweek = strtotime("-7 days", $date);
    $monday = strtotime("last Monday", $date);
} else if($date!='' ){
    $monday = strtotime("last Monday", $date);
} else {
    $date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $monday = strtotime("last Monday", $date);
}
```

edit: i don't get why i got -1 to my question :(

Comment: `date('D',$date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out if a given date is a day of the week, use the "D" flag for the date function.

```
if(date('D', $unixTimestamp) === 'Mon') {
   //Do what you want here
}
```

You can find more details on the PHP manual page for the date function here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php